# Turn a region and points inside that region into a mesh

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, regions, mesh

I have a region defined by a polygon and a few points that are inside that region.  I'd like to create a mesh where its boundary is the boundary of the region and the vertices interior to the mesh are the points that I created (or more if needed for compatibility).  How can I create a mesh like this?

```
region = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, -1}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}, {3, 
   0}, {3, -2}, {0, -2}}];
points = RandomPoint[region, 1000];
mesh = createMeshFromRegionAndPoints[region, points];  (* This is the function I need to create *)
```

I know I can create a mesh from the region with `DiscretizeRegion`, but this won't capture the interior vertices.  I can also create a `DelaunayMesh` of the interior points, but given my region is non-convex, the boundary will be exceeded.  If I could somehow "trim" the edges of the `DelaunayMesh` using the region, then that would get me most of what I want (I'm trying to make a `ListDensityPlot` that draws on my region).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `IncludePoints` from the Finite Element Package so that the required interior vertices are in the mesh (along with other vertices to create a valid mesh).  Here is an example:

```
region = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, -1}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}, {3, 
     0}, {3, -2}, {0, -2}}];
points = RandomPoint[region, 1000];
(* Load FEM Package *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(* Use IncludePoints for required interior points *)
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "IncludePoints" -> points, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], Graphics[{Red, (Point[#] & /@ points)}]]
(* Convert Finite Element Mesh To MeshRegion *)
mr = MeshRegion[mesh]
```

[image: Mesh Images]